# Python Regex match string between specific string and end character

Tags: python, regex, match

I am building a file stripper to build a config report, and I have a very very long string as my base data. The following is a very small snippet of it, but it at least illustrates what I'm working with.

Snippet Example: `DEFAULT_GATEWAY=192.168.88.1&DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0=1&DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1=1&DELVRY_SCHEDULE0=1&DELVRY_SNI0=192.168.88.158&DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1=0&`

How would I go about matching the following:

```
between "DEFAULT_GATEWAY=" and "&"
between "DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0=" and "&"
between "DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1=" and "&"
between "DELVRY_SCHEDULE=" and "&"
between "DELVRY_SNI0=" and "&"
between "DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1=" and "&"
```

and building a dict with it like:

```
{"DEFAULT_GATEWAY":"192.168.88.1",
 "DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0":"1",
 "DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1":"1",
 "DELVRY_SCHEDULE0":"1",
 "DELVRY_SNI0":"0",
 "DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1":"0"}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

```
In [1]: input = 'DEFAULT_GATEWAY=192.168.88.1&DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0=1&DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1=1&DELVRY_SCHEDULE0=1&DELVRY_SNI0=192.168.88.158&DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1=0&'

In [2]: input.split('&')
Out[2]: 
['DEFAULT_GATEWAY=192.168.88.1',
 'DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0=1',
 'DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1=1',
 'DELVRY_SCHEDULE0=1',
 'DELVRY_SNI0=192.168.88.158',
 'DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1=0',
 '']

In [3]: [keyval.split('=') for keyval in input.split('&') if keyval]
Out[3]: 
[['DEFAULT_GATEWAY', '192.168.88.1'],
 ['DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0', '1'],
 ['DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1', '1'],
 ['DELVRY_SCHEDULE0', '1'],
 ['DELVRY_SNI0', '192.168.88.158'],
 ['DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1', '0']]

In [4]: dict(keyval.split('=') for keyval in input.split('&') if keyval)
Out[4]: 
{'DEFAULT_GATEWAY': '192.168.88.1',
 'DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0': '1',
 'DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1': '1',
 'DELVRY_SCHEDULE0': '1',
 'DELVRY_SNI0': '192.168.88.158',
 'DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1': '0'}
```

Notes

1. This is the input line
2. Split by `&` to get pairs of key-values. Note the last entry is empty
3. Split each entry by the equal sign while throwing away empty entries
4. Build a dictionary

## Another Solution

```
In [8]: import urlparse

In [9]: urlparse.parse_qsl(input)
Out[9]: 
[('DEFAULT_GATEWAY', '192.168.88.1'),
 ('DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0', '1'),
 ('DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1', '1'),
 ('DELVRY_SCHEDULE0', '1'),
 ('DELVRY_SNI0', '192.168.88.158'),
 ('DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1', '0')]

In [10]: dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(input))
Out[10]: 
{'DEFAULT_GATEWAY': '192.168.88.1',
 'DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0': '1',
 'DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1': '1',
 'DELVRY_SCHEDULE0': '1',
 'DELVRY_SNI0': '192.168.88.158',
 'DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1': '0'}
```

Comment: Beat me to it... Good one. I saw this question late and I was almost done writing this exact solution.

Comment: I am lucky this time. Usually, I am pretty late to the game

Comment: Perfect and elegant solution. Thanks! This not only gave me the specific key value pairs I wanted, but the entirety of pairs in the config for ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Split first by '&' to get a list of strings, then by '=', like this:

```
d = dict(kv.split('=') for kv in line.split('&'))
```

Comment: You are missing one check for empty entries.

Comment: He just posted a snippet, it's not clear if empty entries are actually possible.

Comment: Look at other answers, it is certainly possible. All you are missing is `if kv`.

Comment: Just because he added the check doesn't mean it's possible, the only empty entry is the trailing one, which might just be because it's a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

keys = {"DEFAULT_GATEWAY",
    "DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL0",
    "DELVRY_AGGREGATION_INTERVAL1",
    "DELVRY_SCHEDULE0",
    "DELVRY_SNI0",
    "DELVRY_USE_SSL_TLS1"}
resdict = {}
for k in keys:
    pat = '{}([^&])&'.format(k)
    mo = re.search(pat, bigstring)
    if mo is None: continue  # no match
    resdict[k] = mo.group(1)
```

will leave your desired result in `resdict`, if `bigstring` is the string you're searching in.

This assumes you know in advance which keys you'll be looking for, and you keep them in a set `keys`.  If you don't know in advance the keys of interest, that's a very different issue of course.